# Empty while loop without which the code doesn't work

Tags: c++, arduino

I ran into some code for a sumo robot. I don't understand why *while(BTN)* is used in the code. What is the use of the while loop?

Without the first *while(BTN)* the code doesn't work, without the second one the robot doesn't stop. All relevant code is listed below.

```
#include <Wire.h>
void setup() {
  //Button
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(A2, HIGH);
  #define BTN !digitalRead(A2)
void loop() {
  Forward(0, 0); //Stop motors 
  delay(100);
if (BTN) { //Turn on program with button
    while (BTN) {}
    while (!BTN) { //stop robot if button is pushed again
//code to move the robot was included here
} 
while(BTN){}
 }
}
```

Comment: i tried to fix the code format but you are missing a `}`

Comment: I believe `while (BTN) {}` waits for the button to be released to prevent multiple triggering from a single button press.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the code after `BTN` has been expanded:

```
if (!digitalRead(A2)) {
    while (!digitalRead(A2)) {}
    while (digitalRead(A2)) {
        // move code
    }
    while (!digitalRead(A2)) {}
}
```

So it’s saying:

- if the button is down;
- wait until it is no longer down;
- then do movement code until the button is down again
- and wait until it’s no longer down.

(**Note** This code doesn’t consider switch bounce at all, it’s likely to behave somewhat erratically.)